# How to translate org.eclipse.compare?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, internationalization, eclipse-rcp

In my current Eclipse RCP project im using the org.eclipse.compare. I'm supposed to translate the texts into german. (Stuff like "Next Difference"...). So far i tried the following:

1. Created a plugin fragment for org.eclipse.compare.
2. copied the plugin.properties from org.eclipse.compare in the new fragment
3. renamed it to plugin_de.properties und translated some parts.
4. setting the checkbox on the plugins tab in the launch config.

Doesn't work. I'm still seeing the english texts. Is there something i forget or  misunderstood?

Comment: Do you have `Bundle-Localization: plugin` in the `MANIFEST.MF` of  the plugin? I think it is needed.

Comment: You mean in the plugin, i want to translate?  Yeah, its there.

Comment: I meant the plugin fragment, looks like it has to be there as well.

Comment: Tried that to. No success.

Comment: Does it matter where the plugin is? I have the eclipse compare plugin in my target platform. But the my translation-fragment in my workspace. The targetplatform is set correctly.

Comment: It's kind of embarrassing, but the week was though... i translated to wrong text.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of embarrassing, but the week was though... i translated the wrong text.